Choosing $5$ cards such that all $5$ cards are from $3$ ranks (number of cards per rank doesn't matter).
I need to find the number of ways to choose $5$ cards from a standard deck such that these cards are from $3$ ranks but the number of cards per rank is not specified. I have two methods, tell me which is wrong and why.
The first method involves case work : since $5$ cards can be split among $3$ ranks in two ways $(2 + 2 + 1, 3 + 1 + 1)$ we calculate two numbers (one for each) and add them. For $3 + 1 + 1$ we select a rank and choose $3$ suits from the $4$ available ones, and then we choose $2$ other ranks from the remaining ranks and choose $1$ card from each (this is $13 \cdot C(4,3) \cdot C(12,2) \cdot 4 \cdot 4)$. For $2 + 2 + 1$ its a similar procedure, we choose a rank, choose a card from it and then choose $2$ ranks and choose $2$ cards from each (this is $13 \cdot 4 \cdot C(12,2) \cdot C(4,2) \cdot C(4,2))$. The total sum is $13 \cdot C(4,3) \cdot C(12,2) \cdot 4 \cdot 4 + 13 \cdot 4 \cdot C(12,2) \cdot C(4,2) \cdot C(4,2)$.
The other method is simpler but involves no case work. It involves choosing $3$ ranks, choosing $1$ card from each rank at first (to guarantee that three ranks have been selected) and then choosing $2$ cards from the remaining $9$ cards of those $3$ ranks ($3$ cards per rank. for $3$ ranks is $9$ cards that can be chosen). This is computed by $C(13,3) \cdot 4  4 \cdot 4 \cdot C(9,2)$.
Which is over/undercounting and why? Keep in mind they both can't be right as they produce drastically different values. The first one produces a much smaller value than the second method.

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Does the suit also matter, or only the rank ?

The second method overcounts.  If two of your cards are the aces of hearts and spades, you count once when the ace of hearts is among the first three cards and again when the ace of spades is among the first three cards.

Only the rank matters.

Consider a simpler scenario: Count the ways to select two suits from the rank of 2.
By the first method you just select two from four suits: $\binom42$ which is $6$.  This is clearly correct. $\{\heartsuit\spadesuit, \heartsuit\clubsuit,\heartsuit\diamondsuit,\spadesuit\clubsuit,\spadesuit\diamondsuit,\clubsuit\diamondsuit\}$.
By the second method you would first select one from four suits, then one from three remaining suits: $\binom 41\binom31$ which is $12$.  That overcounts by a factor of $2!$, which is the number of ways to permute two suits into first and second pick.  But order of selection is not to be counted.

Taking each card as distinct (i.e. both rank and suit matter), the second method overcounts. If you fractionate a selection by first laying down an "insurance carpet" to take care of constraints and then select the "remainder", you will overcount because the same item may have been selected for the  "insurance carpet" at one time, and for the "remainder" at another.
Just look up "fractionate" on this site to get numerous exanples that explain this mistake, often committed by students.
Coming to the first method, with your clarification  that only the rank matters, the answer is much simpler,
for $3-1-1$ and $2-2-1$ configurations of ranks,
$\small{C(13,1)\cdot C(12,2)  + C(13,2) \cdot C(11,1)}$.
Normally, though, each card is taken to be distinct (i.e. both rank and suit matter), in which case your  formula for the first method is correct, viz
$\small{13 \cdot C(4,3) \cdot C(12,2) \cdot 4 \cdot 4 + 13 \cdot 4 \cdot C(12,2) \cdot C(4,2) \cdot C(4,2)}$
